# Vue.js - How to add multiple layout in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm creating a vuejs app, in which I want to have two different layouts like one for user interface and other for the admin interface.
In the user interface, I have a button named "Admin Panel" on click to this button want to go the admin side and render the new layout. So far I have done this as follows:

- I have created a container folder in my src to keep the layout files

  - UserPanel.vue
  - AdminPanel.vue
- And also a router folder to keep the route files

  - user.js
  - admin.js
  - index.js

###UserPanel.js###

```
<template>
  <v-app> 
    <h4>User Layout</h4>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
export default {
}
</script>
```

###AdminPanel.js###

```
<template>
  <v-app> 
    <h4>Admin Layout</h4>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>
```

###user.js###

```
import UserPanel from 'Container/UserPanel';
const HomeV1 = () => import('Views/HomeV1');
const HomeV2 = () => import('Views/HomeV2');
const HomeV3 = () => import('Views/HomeV3');

export default{
  path: '/',
  component: UserPanel,
  redirect:'/home',
  children:[
    { 
        path: '/',               
        component: HomeV1 ,
        meta: {
            header: 1
         }
    },
    { 
        path: '/home',               
        component: HomeV1 ,
        meta: {
            header: 1
         }
    },
    { 
        path: '/home-two',               
        component: HomeV2 ,
        meta: {
            header: 2
        }
    },
    { 
        path: '/home-three',               
        component: HomeV3 ,
        meta: {
            header: 3
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

###admin.js###

```
import Admin from 'Container/Adminpanel.vue';
const Reports = () => import('Views/AdminPanel/Reports.vue');
const Invoice = () => import('Views/AdminPanel/Invoices.vue');
const AdminAccount = () => import('Views/AdminPanel/Account.vue');

export default {
  path: '/admin-panel',
  component: Admin,
  redirect:'/admin-panel/reports',
  children:[
    { 
        path: '/admin-panel/reports',  
        component: Reports, 
        name:'Reports'
    },
    { 
        path: '/admin-panel/invoices',  
        component: Invoice, 
        name:'Invoice'
    },
    { 
        path: '/admin-panel/products',  
        component: AdminProducts, 
        name:'AdminProducts'
    }
  ]
}
```

###index.js###

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import userRoutes from './user';
import adminRoutes from './admin';
Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    userRoutes,
    adminRoutes
  ]
})
```

Now only my user routing is working. To show the pages of admin I have to put its route in user.js and after that, it renders the user's layout not admin's layout.

Thank You.

Comment: in your admin.js you set the children wrong. the path sholud be `path: '/reports'` not `path: '/admin-panel/reports'` (unless your want you link like /admin-panel/admin-panel/reports). the children get the parent prefix path auto. idk if its answer your question. i still dont understand what the problem you have. which route doesn't work?

Comment: but it still renders the user's layout and show URL is not defined

Comment: @elichen see, from front-end  when I click on "admin panel" button to go on the admin side here on clicking im changing the url from "localhost:8080/home" to "localhost:8080/admin-panel/reports"  and on wrong route i'm showing a not found message using this path ({ path: '/*',redirect:"not-found"}) in my user.js

Comment: if you use  ({ path: '/*',redirect:"not-found"}) in your user.js. its break all the routers after this . so its never reach the routers after this. in other words, your admin.js routers cannot be reached. and btw in your case its sholud be localhost:8080/admin-panel/admin-panel/reports

Comment: @elichen I have fixed the URL issue by removing "admin-panel". After removing the "not found path" I am getting an error , here you can see `tinyurl.com/y3lyyst6`  open this link by using prefix "http://"

Comment: this error related to your ProductEdit.vue component. but now you can see. its actually load the correct route. btw you have a duplicates routes. so one thing for sure now its load your admins views correctly as you can see. and about this error. we need more code because this error actually related to the component itself not to router anymore (looks like you trying to access data in ProductEdit component but this data not initialize)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195341/discussion-between-shashi-verma-and-eli-chen).

Answer (score 2):

Put attribute meta in the route like this:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/admin',
    name: 'admin',
    meta: { layout: 'LayoutAdmin' },
    component: Dashboard,
  },
```

and in App.vue you can render depends of this condition `this.$route.meta.layout` here an example:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <notifications width="400px" />
    <LayoutAdmin v-if="this.$route.meta.layout">
      <router-view class="content" />
    </LayoutAdmin>
    <LayoutDefault v-else :links="links" :headerButtons="headerButtons">
      <router-view class="content" />
    </LayoutDefault>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have played around with this before and the way I did it was to have alternative layouts that switch depending on a [route meta field](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html)...

So when you define a route, you can add a meta field:

```
path: '/admin-panel/reports',  
        component: Reports, 
        name:'Reports',
        meta: { template: 'admin' }
```

Then you need to check routes as they change. The easiest way to do this is in a global navigation guard (like the example has on their page). If it detects it's an admin page, it changes a Vuex property which will then switch which template you're using.

I will say that in the end I stopped using this method and wrapped all of my pages with wrapper components (admin/user/etc) so I could control everything from Vue itself. This was mainly due to Vue Router's limitations around waiting for a user to be authenticated though so that may not be an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">

    <div >
      <div id="AdminTemplate" v-if="this.$route.meta.layout == 'AdminTemplate'">
        <router-view />
      </div>
    <div id="NormalTemplate" v-else>
        <router-view />
    </div>
  
  </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

And in the router

```
{
    path: "/admin",
    name: "AdminVue",
    component: AdminVue,
    meta: { layout: 'AdminTemplate' },
  }
```