# Display layout based on boolean from Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I got Vue2 app with `vue-router` with routings configured like that:

```
export default {
  path: "/",
  redirect: "/dashboard",
  component: AdminLayout,
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: "/dashboard",
      name: "Dashboard",
      component: Dashboard
    },
    {
      path: "/add/user",
      name: "InviteUser",
      component: InviteUser
    },
    {
      path: "/groups",
      name: "Groups",
      component: Groups
    },
   ...
```

In app, we got two different types of users - admin and normal user. Some of those routings should be accessible for both, but the problem is that user should see different layout base on its type (permission) - `AdminLayout` for admins and `UserLayout` for normal users.

Is there any way to show app which template should user see based on boolean from vuex with keeping route path?

- on `/dashboard` admin will see dashboard with `AdminLayout`
- on `/dashboard` normal user will see dashboard with `UserLayout`

My main routing cofig:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import SessionRoutes from "./session.js";
import AdminRoutes from "./admin.js";
import defaultRoutes from "./default";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [AdminRoutes, SessionRoutes, defaultRoutes];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Take look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56701836/vue-js-how-to-add-multiple-layout-in-vuejs) pls.

Comment: Seems not really pretty way to do this.

Comment: That's one of the many things nuxt handles REALLY well (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/views#layouts). Maybe it's an option for you.

Comment: I agree, but I got almost all app  finished with VueCLI, so switching to Nuxt at this moment doesn't make sense :/

Comment: What are AdminLayout/UserLayout ? are they just components? If so, it might be possible to have the component part in routes array as a function and return the desired component from that function. The key here is that any function that has the mandatory fields can be used as Vue Component

Comment: Like `component:isAdmin ? AdminLayout : UserLayout` or `component: () => isAdmin ? AdminLayout : UserLayout` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set a condition in the layout part on the current page for example for when you use nuxt:

```
<script>
  export default {
      layout: (ctx) => (ctx.isAdmin ? 'adminLayout' : 'userLayout'),
  }
</script>
```

but I opine you don't use Nuxt.js and I think below solution is suitable for your question:

1. Using the meta-object in our route
2. set dynamic component on app.vue page
3. code for about.vue page

```js
    import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
    import About from '../views/About.vue'
    import LayoutA from '../layouts/LayoutA.vue'
    import LayoutB from '../layouts/LayoutB.vue'
    Vue.use(VueRouter)
    const routes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home,
        meta: { layout: LayoutA }
      },
      {
        path: '/about',
        name: 'About',
        component: About,
        meta: { layout: LayoutB }
      }
    ]
    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: 'history',
      base: process.env.BASE_URL,
      routes
    })
    
    export default router;
```

```html
<!--app.vue page -->

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <component :is="this.$route.meta.layout || 'div'">
      <router-view />
    </component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>


<!--about page-->
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "About"
};
</script>
```

Comment: We got two layouts for two pages. I need to find solution to display one page with one of two layouts based on user permission.

Comment: @BobiDaHombre. please look at this [page](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/multiple-layouts-for-vue-spa-app-fafda6b2bfc7)

Answer (score 0):

To get a different layout working for the dashboard and all child routes your layouts have to use [the **router view** component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html). I use a wrapper component to handle this in one of my projects following this approach.

Excerpt from my router config:

```js
…
  {
    component: MainFrame,
    name: 'main',
    path: '/',
    redirect: 'dashboard',
    children: [
      {
        alias: 'dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        name: 'dashboard',
        path: '', // Default child route → be equivalent to /dashboard
      },
      {
        path: "add/user",
        name: "InviteUser",
        component: InviteUser
      },
      {
        path: "groups",
        name: "Groups",
        component: Groups
      },
    ],
  },
…
```

In your `MainFrame` component you can wrap your layout in a [dynamic component](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view). So you can switch your layout easely based on a Vuex getter:

**MainFrame.vue**

```html
<template>
  <component :is="layout">
    <!-- you can use slots too if you like -->
  </component>
</template>

<script>
import AdminLayout from './AdminLayout'
import UserLayout from './UserLayout'

export default {
  computed: {
    layout() {
      return this.$store.getters['isAdminUser'] ? AdminLayout : UserLayout
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And your layouts have to use `<router-view />`. It works as a wrapper for all nested routes and therefore you have only one place to handle the layout for the dashboard and child pages:

**AdminLayout.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="auth-view">
    <header>…</header>
    <aside>…</aside>
    <main>
      <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
        <router-view />
      </transition>
    </main>
    <footer>…</footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

**UserLayout.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="guest-view">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

---

**EDIT:**

This approach can be used for deeper nesting too. Assuming your user route should have another child routes you can solve this on the router config using a `<router-view />` within a render function:

```js
…
      // Let's split down user related routes
      {
        component: { render: (h) => h('router-view') },
        name: 'usersView',
        path: 'users',
        redirect: 'ListUsers',
        children: [
          // Show users
          {
            path: '', // route: /users/
            name: 'ListUsers',
            component: ListUsers
          },
          // Show a single user
          {
            path: ':id', // route: /users/{userId}
            name: 'ViewUser',
            component: ViewUser
          },
          // Invite new users
          {
            path: 'add', // route: /users/add
            name: 'InviteUser',
            component: InviteUser
          },
        ]
      }
…
```

Comment: This makes me adding this code on every page. It's not efficient

Comment: @BobiDaHombre I get it. So I've updated my answer with a more complex answer but this should meet your expectations in a better way.