# How to conditionally render multiple components based on route without affecting layout in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue-router4

I have a navbar and two side menus which I use in multiple pages. But for a number of pages I don't want to have the side menu.

I have tried using v-if with $router.name, but because I was using a grid system, the layout would break. Then also it was impossible to add more than one component to not render the side menus.

This is the template:

```
<template>
    <TheNavbar/>
    <div class="container">
      <TheLeftMenu/>
      <router-view/>
      <TheRightMenu/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: it can be done in many ways, like [passing props from route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode) or using [multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56701836/vue-js-how-to-add-multiple-layout-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 1):

My solution to avoid the grid system to squash the router-view component was to divide the template in two, one using the sidemenus, the other without them.

Then in order to have multiple pages to not load the side menus I used a computed property to hold an array with all the routes to not render the side menus:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="blockedRoutes.includes($route.name) == false">
    <TheNavbar/>
    <div class="container">
      <TheLeftMenu/>
      <router-view/>
      <TheRightMenu/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <TheNavbar/>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

```
  computed: {
    blockedRoutes () {
      return ['Register', 'SignIn', 'About']
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the simple method of a flex container;

```html
<template>
<router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
 <div class="holder">
  <div>
   <TheLeftMenu/>
  </div">
  <div class="main">
   <transition name="fade" mode="out-in"><component :is="Component" /></transition>
  </div>
  <div v-if="!route.meta.hideRmenu">
   <TheRightMenu/>
  </div>
 </div>
</router-view>
</template>

<style>
.holder{
 display : flex;
 width : 100%;
 /*if you want your container not to grow with the page do the following*/
 overflow: hidden;
 height : 100vh;
}
.holder .main{
 flex : 1;
 flex-direction: row;
 
 /*if you want your container not to grow with the page do the following*/
 max-height : 100vh;
 overflow : auto;
}
.holder :not(.main){
 min-width: 32px;
}
</style>
```

This way you can, if you want, also add [transitions](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#the-transition-component).
If you don't want to use transitions, you just need to remove the transitions tags.

This aproach uses is focused for `Vue 3` and uses [Scoped Slots](https://https:/vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots)